# Sinhala unicode (Wijesekara keyboard) in iBus on Ubuntu 14.04 not working

Tags: 14.04, keyboard-layout, ibus

I tried to install Wijesekara keyboard layout on my Ubuntu 14.04. I used http://www.siyabas.lk/sinhala_how_to_install.html#lin that method. but I got an error.

```
Package ttf-sinhala-lklug is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it: fonts-lklug-sinhala
E: Package 'ttf-sinhala-lklug' has no installation candidate
```

What should I do?

Comment: If anyone wants, the most recent method that I used is [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1106023/566752).

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS x86 x64 tested

1. Run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install fonts-lklug-sinhala ibus im-switch ibus-m17n m17n-db m17n-contrib language-pack-si-base
   ```
2. Logout and login (No need to reboot)
3. Type following command in the terminal and go to the input method tab

   ```
   ibus-setup
   ```
4. Configure ibus settings to use Sinhala.

   a. Select `input method`

   [image]

   b. Select `Add`

   c. Select `Sinhala-Sinhalese` and `OK`

   d. Click `En` in Top right corner of your screen.

   [image]

   e. Change it to `Sinhala`

Enjoy!

Comment: මේක වැඩ කරනව 16.04 LTS වලටත්. ස්තුතියි!! This solution works for 16.04 LTS as well. Thanks!!!

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS you need to install `im-config` instead of `im-switch`

Answer (score 2):

It clearly says

```
However the following packages replace it: fonts-lklug-sinhala
```

So replace `ttf-sinhala-lklug` with `fonts-lklug-sinhala`. Which will make full command like

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-lklug-sinhala ibus im-switch ibus-m17n m17n-db m17n-contrib language-pack-si-base
```

Answer (score 2):

I have created a custom XKB symbols mapping file to make the Sinhala installation work with Wijesekara layout. All the information you need to know about using it is in the git hub repository.

This may not be the best solution. But serves the purpose. https://github.com/para-d/si-wijesekara-keyboard

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using SL software repository which `ttf-sinhala-lklug` isn't available.

Just follow the below steps,

- Open a terminal ( Pressing Ctrl-Alt-T )
- Open software-properties-gtk, `sudo software-properties-gtk` This will open Software Sources manager
- Then change the server to the Main server. You can also enable repositories from that window

[image: Ubuntu Software Tab]

Now you will be able to install `ttf-sinhala-lklug` once you update your software repository.

More information can be found in the [Ubuntu Official Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)